# Angular Material Stepper is undefined on first load

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-stepper

I'm using Angular Material Stepper in a component. The problem is that when the component loads for the first time it breaks with the error message

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined
```

My Template

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
        <!-- Steps -->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>    
<div>
    <button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
    <button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === stepper._steps.length-1">Next</button>
</div
```

My TS

```
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';

goBack(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.previous();
}

goForward(stepper: MatStepper){
    stepper.next();
}
```

And I also have stepper defined in TS as

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
```

But if I use the [disabled] property as

```
<div>
    <button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper ? stepper.selectedIndex === 0 : false">Back</button>
    <button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button" 
        [disabled]="stepper ? stepper.selectedIndex === stepper._steps.length-1 : false">Next</button>
</div
```

than the stepper works as expected.

**Note:**

```
Angular Version is :5.2.8
Angular Material Version:5.2.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Elvis operator** :

```
<button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
    [disabled]="stepper?.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
```

It's the equivalent of

```
<button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
    [disabled]="stepper ? stepper.selectedIndex === 0 : false">Back</button>
```

But cleaner. For the click event, you can do this

```
<button (click)="stepper && goBack(stepper)" type="button" 
    [disabled]="stepper?.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
```

To prevent the call if the stepper is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my problem is that I need stepper to be defined on first load

Comment: @tayyab_fareed your stepper won't be defined until displayed, You don't have a choice there. You will have to defer your processing to **until the stepper is loaded**. In the template, that's done with the elvis operator. If it still doesn't work, please provide a [mcve] or the TS code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

ViewChild gets it's value after view init hook, but angular try to read it after init hook

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

if you'd like to update your project to angular 8, you'll get tools to define when you need to inflate ViewChild variable

https://v8.angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Comment: Is there any way out for angular 5?

Comment: i don't think so
but why you need this after init?
do you have any logic that have to be resolved before after view init hook?